# Sql Data as tree structure to bind a asp.net grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have a sql query like

```
SELECT   
       A.Id
      ,C.[inv_number]
      ,C.[inv_date]
      ,C.[com_id]
      ,C.[com_name]
      ,C.[total_amount] as AmountDr
      ,sum(A.total_amount) as AmountCr
      ,B.category
  FROM invoice_break_up A 
  left join fee_category B on A.fee_id= B.fee_id 
  left join invoice_master C on A .invoice_id=C.invoice_id
  where A.total_amount>0
  group by A.invoice_id,A.fee_id,B.category,C.[inv_number]
      ,C.[inv_date]
      ,C.[com_id]
      ,C.[com_name]
      ,C.[total_amount]
      ,C.[created_date]
```

i am getting the result as expected like [image]

But i need to get the result as [image]

The result i need to bind to a asp.net gridview. Is there any way for this. Please help.

Comment: What do you want to do? update the question clearly

Comment: I need to get the result as second image.

Comment: There is some issue in query is it? if so please paste some sample data. so that people can help you!!

Comment: getting result after executing query like first image.

Comment: You want the AmountDr and com_name to be shown once? I guess.

Comment: Yes,because amountCr data is breakup of amountDr. So i need to show it as like com_name group.

Comment: I am posting a sample that will get the AmountDr once for the time being. Get the other according to yours.

Comment: Thank you..I am waiting for your answer.

Comment: Did the solution work?

Comment: Yes @AT-2016. Thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following to get the required output:

Table name: Table_Group

```
GroupId - Name

1 - Food

2 - TV
```

Table name: Table_Product

```
ProductId - GroupId - ProductName

1 - 1 - Pepsi

2 - 1 - 7up

3 - 1 - Fanta

4 - 2 - Sony

5 - 2 - LG
```

Table name: Table_Location

```
LocationId - GroupId - LocationName

1 - 1 - Bangladesh

2 - 2 - China
```

Finally run the following script: **Modified**

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN t.ProductId = (SELECT TOP 1 ProductId -- Sub query
FROM Table_Product t3
WHERE t3.GroupId = t.GroupId
ORDER BY t3.GroupId) THEN q.LocationName
ELSE ''
END AS LocationName,

CASE WHEN t.ProductId = (SELECT TOP 1 t2.ProductId -- Sub query
FROM Table_Product t2
WHERE t2.GroupId = p.GroupId
ORDER BY t2.GroupId) THEN p.Name
ELSE ''
END AS Category, 

t.ProductName
FROM Table_Product t
LEFT JOIN Table_Group p ON p.GroupId = t.GroupId
LEFT JOIN Table_Location q ON q.GroupId = t.GroupId
ORDER BY t.GroupId
```

The output - Previous:

[image: Demo]

**Updated:**

[image: Demo_02]